# How do you display detail page when the respective listview item is tapped

Tags: flutter

I am trying to pass the id of listview item to a different page with so it can populate a listview with items referenced by that id:

```
return SideHeaderListView(
                        itemCount: order.length,
                        itemExtend: 230.0,
                        headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
                          return new SizedBox(
                            child: Text(order[index]['Month'],
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.green,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  fontSize: 30.0),),);
                        },
                        hasSameHeader: (int a, int b) {
                            return order[a]['Month'] ==
                                order[b]['Month'];

                        },
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
                          String value;
                          return new GestureDetector(
                              //onLongPress: _showPopupMenu(),
                              onTap: () {
                                Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) =>
                                        MyItemList(orders: order[index],)
                                ));
                              },
```

This is the code that passes the id and inserts the id into the table:

```
    class MyItemList extends StatelessWidget{

  final Map<String, dynamic> orders;
 // final Items items;
  MyItemList({this.orders});
}

FlatButton(
              color: Colors.lightGreen,
              child: Text('ADD',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
              onPressed: () async {
                OrderProvider.insertItem({
                  'ref':MyItemList().orders,
                  'Quantity': _quantityController.text,
                  'Unit': getDropDownItem().toString(),
                  'TypeOfProduct': _typeController.text,
                  'UnitPrice':_unitpriceController.text,
                  'TotalPrice':getTotalPrice()
                });
```

This  is my provider class method:

```
return await db.rawQuery(
      "select * from Items where ref = ${MyItemList(orders: id,)}",);
  }
```

Comment: Can you share all your MyItemList class?

Comment: https://github.com/ryanchege254/order_app/tree/master/lib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I can suggest you to use a StateFul widget Instead of a StateLess widget in your `MyItemList Class`, then In the `InitState` you can get the data based in the respective Id, for example:

```
class MyItemList extends StatefulWidget {
  // final Map<String, dynamic> orders; 
  // instead of receive a Map receive only the OrderID
  final int orderId;

  MyItemList({this.orderId});

  @override
  _MyItemListState createState() => _MyItemListState();
}

class _MyItemListState extends State<MyItemList> {
  List<dynamic> itemsToSave;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getItems(widget.orderId);
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }

  getItems(int orderId) async {
    itemsToSave = await yourProvider.getItems(orderId);
    print(itemsToSave);
  }
}
```

And in your provider is better to use the `whereArgs` for example:

```
await db.rawQuery(
    'SELECT * FROM Items WHERE ref = ?',
    [order],
  ),
```

And if you have a map of orders, is better to iterate the map and get the data of each item separately or check the `IN Operator` documentation for [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html) for more explanation you can check this [post](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-in/).

Hope it helps.

Comment: How do I use the initstate

Comment: Using a StateFul Widget,  I updated my answer and this article can help you to understand more about the Widget Lifecycle: https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-lifecycle-for-android-and-ios-developers-8f532307e0c7.

Comment: And also to clarify, in my future builder am i still gonna call the new method   getItems(int orderId)

Comment: `order` is the parameter you receive in your provider, and yes you can call yourProvider.getItems('xOrder') in a `future`.

Comment: Help me with making the necessary changes with the provider class as well, await db.rawQuery( 'SELECT * FROM Items WHERE ref = ?', [order], ), how do Initialize the var order

Comment: I keep getting a database exception that DatabaseException(the bind value at index 1 is null) sql 'select * from Items where refID = ?' args [null]})

Comment: Are you passing the `order` in the array `['yourOrderIdHere']`?

Comment: yes I am , the '[order]' has been initialised as an int and i've updated my question title